# configuration of email server

Tags: windows, email, iis

I have an email script in asp that worked fine, but now I moved to my own windows server 2008 and can not seem to put it to work. It always gives this error:

```
CDO.Message.1 error '80040213'
The transport failed to connect to the server.
```

This is not script error because the same page in other host works fine.
It must be the server configuration. Any suggestions?

I am using:

- windows server 2008
- IIS 7,5

Answer (score 1):

First of all what is the script using to send emails?

SMTP or E-Mail library used by .NET (like Sendmail used in PHP)

From the sound of the error message there is no SMTP available on the server. Sometimes new installs do not have this installed at all and require Exhange or SMTP modules installed.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Im using cdo with asp classic and like i said it works fine in another server, is there any way i can get a step by step to see if anything missing in config server? i set permissions for door 25 and 587 and set the smtp email in iis.

Comment: Look inside the error log of windows event viewer, there will be a detailed description.. if there is no log there then find SMTP settings and inside the properties there is a Logging Level. Set the most detailed, run the script again. Check event viewer.

Comment: cant seem to see nothing here:                               2012-05-11 10:02:17 192.164.1.200 - 192.164.1.75 21 ControlChannelOpened - - 0 0 1dd12bc5-36a5-405f-a806-510b700d4148 -
2012-05-11 10:02:49 192.164.1.200 - 192.164.1.75 21 USER ftp_u 530 11001 37 1dd12bc5-36a5-405f-a806-510b700d4148 -
2012-05-11 10:03:16 192.164.1.200 - 192.164.1.75 21 ControlChannelClosed - - 64 0 1dd12bc5-36a5-405f-a806-510b700d4148 -

Comment: what level is logging set to? put it higher- Besisdes that is not the event log- its the SMTP log.

Comment: i just notice that even tho i instaled smtp server i dont have that option in iis, only have smtp email in asp.net group

Comment: ok, think i got it.           2012-05-11 12:45:29 ::1 POST /email.asp actnow=gonow&var_mal=contac|85|80040213|The_transport_failed_to_connect_to_the_server.__ 80 - ::1 Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT+6.1;+WOW64;+rv:12.0)+Gecko/20100101+Firefox/12.0 500 0 0 19

Comment: Yea. it looks like there is not host specified or it using IPv6? technically should work but localhost is better. What happens when you try and log into the SMTP of that server using putty for example. You should get a welcome message

Comment: dont use putty... tryed with localhost, 127.0.0.1 and actual ip and nothing, really dont know what to trye more :(

Comment: putty is free and very good. check my update how to check- you see my server says only authorised users..

Comment: Sorry for the delay but had some problems with the server. tryed wat you said with putty, the cmd window open and then closes without showing any message

Comment: most likley cannot connect to it. You need to connect to smtp and make sure it is running and accepting connections

Comment: never done this before.....

Comment: im so lost, following this toturial http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6_0YBKHT4k8  hope i can get it